# cannot open shared object file, despite it being exactly there

Tags: c, makefile

The following is the content of my `makefile.lnx`:

```
PATHDIR = ../../..
PATHINC = $(PATHDIR)/include
PATHLIB = $(PATHDIR)/lib/linux

CC    = gcc
CFLAGS = -I. -I.. -I$(PATHINC) -O3

all:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.c ../SimpleLCP_Path.o -L$(PATHLIB) -lpath47 -lm
```

I am in its folder and run `ls ../../../include`, which will give a bunch of `.h` files. Running

```
$ ls ../../../lib/linux
libpath47.a  libpath47.so
```

Which is exactly mirroring the path structure in the makefile.

```
make -f makefile.lnx
```

runs without problems. However,

```
$ ./main
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libpath47.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm 99% certain that the exact same file structure and the very same makefile worked on my mac, but I don't have it accessible right now. What's going on here?

Comment: It happens in the runtime, you have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk would I have also had to set that for mac os, and just forgot that I did it at some point - or does it work fundamentally different for the different OS?

Comment: I have never used `MacOS`, all I know is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works on various `Linux`-based systems

Comment: You probably want to explicit the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) at link time (you should prefer some absolute path), but you don't give enough details in your question to get more help. Please provide some [MCVE]. Your current question is unclear.